# Control centre blank on iOS Simulators - no airplane mode button

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Since upgrading Xcode to version 12.3, all iOS simulators (iphone and ipad, versions 13 and 14) show a blank control centre when swiping down from the top right of the screen. I want to activate Airplane Mode, but there are no buttons. Airplane Mode is also missing from the Settings app as well.

Scratching my head on this as it worked fine before, and cannot find any one else reporting this. Has anyone else seen this? Or has this poor Android developer forgotten something fundamental ;-).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you share a ss ?

Comment: No solution so far. I did comment on your workaround below. Thanks.

Comment: did you find an alternative solution or still seems turning off manually ok :)

Answer (score 0):

You can **turn off the Mac ethernet** source if you want to use airplane mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am using this as a workaround for now, but keen to understand why I have lost Airplane Mode.

Comment: did you figure this out? same problem here.